# Cryptography and 3rd party content for submitting iOS apps

Tags: ios, core-data, github, cryptography, app-store

I have 2 questions:

1. When submitting an iOS app to the App Store, Apple asks:

> Is your app designed to use cryptography or does it contain or incorporate cryptography? (Select Yes even if your app is only utilizing the encryption available in iOS or macOS.)

If my app uses Core Data, is it counted as cryptographic?

2. Apple also asks if the app uses 3rd party libraries. Are open-sourced projects on GitHub counted as "3rd party"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding to 1st question , No Core Data is not counted as cryptographic
2nd question, No open-sourced projects are not counted as 3rd party.